# Adding a column to a data extension at email sendtime

Tags: email, ampscript, dataextensions, automation

Here are the details of the project I'm working on:

- I have an automated email workflow
- The first step of automation is generating a new data extension (DX) based on a filter
- I need to populate an email with data from each row of the filtered DX
- This means looping through each row of the DX

I believe the only way to do this is to add a column to the filtered DX, like `rowNum` and then increment each row by 1, so then I can do:

`FOR @cnt = 1 TO DataExtensionRowCount("DX")
    LookupRows("DX", "rowNum", @cnt)
    /* do stuff */
 NEXT @cnt`

The problem is that I would have to create this new `rowNum` column on the fly, either in the email at sendtime OR in a SQL query (not sure ET supports this though). I've tried `UpsertDE()` but if that's it then I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Any thoughts? Let me know if you need any clarification/additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot add additional column in to the filter. I would suggest add `Flag`column with default value to `True` in DataExtension itself so `Filter` DataExtension will generate a new data with Flag column value `True`.

Now, use [LookupOrderedRows](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#LookupOrderedRows) AmpScript function to retrieve each row of the filtered DX.

```
SET @DataCount = LookupOrderedRows("DX",0,"Any DX column name Desc","Flag","True")
For @i = 1 TO RowCount(@DataCount) Do
     /* Do your stuff */
Next @i
```

Hope this solution will help you!

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially the conclusion I came to as well.